# Determining the area of Shapefiles

Tags: r, geospatial

How can one determine the area of a shapefile?

When I use `summary(data)`, it gives the area, but then I have no idea what the area of each shapefile polygons are.

Also, can the area be converted to meters?

Comment: look in the `rgeos` library for function `gArea()`

Comment: Depends on the coordinate system. Show us what `summary(data)` actually gives and maybe we can help more.

Comment: I am working with DIVA-GIS data. And can't figure out the units of the area. If the information is in long-lat if I use the `gArea()` function, how can I know the units of this area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# load the rgeos library
library(rgeos)

# make a polygon (borrowed from ref manual for package)
sample_poly <- readWKT("POLYGON((0 1,0.95 0.31,0.59 -0.81,-0.59 -0.81,-0.95 0.31,0 1))")

# and calculate the area
gArea(sample_poly)
[1] 2.3803
```

Comment: From a shapefile of different countries for instance from DIVA-GIS, how can you figure out the units of that area?

Comment: @JavierM88 I would check the documentation associated with your dataset. Not aware of a location where the units are embedded in the shapefile itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
data@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@area
data@polygons[[2]]@Polygons[[1]]@area
```

Will give you areas of the first and second polygons, you can figue a for loop to give you all or show us the names with:

```
names(data)
```

Comment: `sapply` might be more convenient than `for`: `sapply(data@polygons, function(x) x@Polygons[[1]]@area)`

Comment: This method is dangerous in case you have polygons with hole, as it would not consider the hole and hence over-estimate the area.